# NMR: Link between relaxation time and Chemical shift

Tags: nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I have been taught NMR in both my physics and chemistry high school classes. Everything lines up until they get into how we detect different chemical environments in the compound.

Chemistry class: We use chemical shift values compared to an agreed upon zero value of Si(CH3)4. The less shielded the proton, the higher RF frequency required to promote it to the higher energy orientation.

Physics class: There is a Larmor frequency. It depends on the external field and the gyromagnetic ratio. Angular frequency for the precession can be calculated. RF at this frequency causes resonance for the nuclei with that Larmor frequency. When the promoted protons relax, RF is given off and the relaxation times tell us about the environment of the proton.

I understood the chem approach better and got all the physics before they came to relaxation times since I don't see why relaxation times are different and what this has to do with the Larmor; and how does this all connect to chemical shift from chem class.

Question: What connects these two seemingly different approaches? I think that this Larmor frequency must have something to do with the environment of the proton and maybe that is the link, but I am not sure how.

--Please keep the answers around a highschool/first year undergrad level.--

Comment: I believe shifts and relaxation times tell you different effects of the environment. The shift tells you the induced magnetic field from the surrounding (e.g. due to electrons in chemical bonds), and the relaxation times tell you the "noisiness" of the environment (e.g. fluctuations in the local magnetic field, inhomogeneity, collisions)

Comment: also shifts are measured by looking at changes in larmor frequency w.r.t a reference so the two are based on the same physical picture of spin precession.